# Powershell code from C# doesn't work when "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage" is included

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, powershell, .net-4.5, azure-storage

I have a .NET 4.5 web app (ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application) and my problem seems to be that running *powershell code* with some simple *azure storage* functionality will not work when it is executed from C#. But it will work when executed through the normal powershell console or the ISE.

**Powershell (Just creates a table and inserts a column for testing):**

```
function Test-SetTableValues($storageAccount, $storageKey, $tableName, $valuesHash)
{
    $storageContext = New-AzureStorageContext $storageAccount -StorageAccountKey $storageKey
    $table = New-AzureStorageTable –Name $tableName –Context $storageContext

    $entity = New-Object Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.DynamicTableEntity "PartitionKey", "RowKey"
    foreach ($key in $valuesHash.Keys)
    {
        $entity.Properties.Add($key, $valuesHash[$key])
    }

    $result = $table.CloudTable.Execute([Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableOperation]::InsertOrMerge($entity), $null, $null)
}
Test-SetTableValues("STORAGE_ACCOUNT", "STORAGE_KEY", "TABLE_NAME", @{MyColumn="MyValue"})
```

**It doesn't work when executed through C#:**

```
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;
public static void Test()
        {
            var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
            runspace.Open();
            var powershell = PowerShell.Create();
            powershell.Runspace = runspace;

            powershell.AddScript(/*powershell code here*/);
            powershell.AddCommand("out-default");
            powershell.Invoke();
        }
```

And the reason is because the library *Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage* is included.
If we remove it, the code will work. **But I need it for other things.**

The CLR Version is the same for all environments(c#/ise/powershell_console) as I tried outputing the variable *$PSVersionTable* (CLRVersion 4.0.30319.17400).

The error we get is this:

> Cannot convert argument "operation", with value:
>   "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storag e.Table.TableOperation", for "Execute"
>   to type "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage. Table.TableOperation":
>   "Cannot convert the "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Tabl
>   e.TableOperation" value of type
>   "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableOper ation" to type
>   "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableOperation"." At
>   OurPowershellFile.ps1:90 char:5
>   +     $result = $table.CloudTable.Execute([Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table .Ta
>   ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   ~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument

Thanks in advance for any answers. I just can't find a solution for this!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to microsoft support is seems like modifying the powershell code slightly "fixes" the issue. Not sure why exactly but the below code works.

```
function Test-SetTableValues($storageAccount, $storageKey, $tableName, $valuesHash)
{
    $accountCredentials = New-Object "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth.StorageCredentials" $storageAccount, $storageKey
    $storageAccount = New-Object "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount" $accountCredentials, $true
    $tableClient = $storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient()
    $table = $tableClient.GetTableReference($tableName)
    $table.CreateIfNotExists()

    $entity = New-Object Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.DynamicTableEntity "PartitionKey", "RowKey"
    foreach ($key in $valuesHash.Keys)
    {
        $entity.Properties.Add($key, $valuesHash[$key])
    }

    $result = $table.Execute([Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableOperation]::InsertOrMerge($entity))
}
Test-SetTableValues("STORAGE_ACCOUNT", "STORAGE_KEY", "TABLE_NAME", @{MyColumn="MyValue"})
```